# Read and Write to current editor pane from IntelliJ plugin (plugin-dev)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is it possible to get the current editor pane and edit the contents from an IntelliJ (IDEA) plugin?

I'd like to for example, select some text in the current editor and overwrite it with my own.

I've got this far;

```
Editor editor = FileEditorManager.getInstance(event.getProject()).getSelectedTextEditor();
VisualPosition position = editor.getCaretModel().getVisualPosition();
Document document = editor.getDocument();
document.insertString(position.column, Character.toString(text.charAt(offset)));
```

where `event` is `AnActionEvent` coming in from the `AnAction` class.

but it doesn't update the editor panel.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Architectural+Overview
for some general guidance.

It would be easier to answer your question if you specify your exact usecase.

Comment: you must obey read/write rules as outlined in paragraph "General Threading Rules"

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.replaceString(start,end,replaceSting)` to replace text in editor.

For more information, see [Working with Text](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/working-with-text.html):